# Hide radiobutton but show pseudo-element?

Tags: css

I'm trying to hide a `radio-button` and use `:before` to create a custom one.

Here is my CSS:

```
input[type=radio]{
    display: none;  
}

input[type=radio]:before{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;  

    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

I expect this to generate an empty square. The problem seems to be that when I apply `display: none` to my input, this also effects the `:before` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="radio" id="r1" name = "r1" class="rdb" style="visibility:hidden" />
<label for="r1">Male</label>
<input type="radio" id="r2" name = "r2" class="rdb" style="visibility:hidden" />
<label for="r2">Female</label>
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/M9HHS/)

Comment: Using "visibility:hidden", however, removes the keyboard accessibility of the form elements.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the radio itself to be 0px wide by 0px high: so the pseudo element is shown but the radio itself is not visible.

```
input[type=radio]{ width:0; height:0;}
```

Example http://jsbin.com/AYIGuyi/1/edit

Comment: I lke this idea, but in the latest version of chrome this output's a small radio-button.

Comment: And you can't hide it with opacity either as it is applied to the pseudo element too :-(

Answer (score 0):

That is expected behaviour. `:before` and `:after` are applied INSIDE elements and so obey the the same display rules.

I think the Checkbox Hack might be what you need.

[**CSS-Tricks article**](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)

Answer (score 0):

Or, there is another way, without using labels:

1. Set `visibility: hidden;` to a radio button
2. Set `visibility: visible;` to its ::before pseudo element

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).